# delete query is runing and not delete any data

Tags: mysql

I use a query to delete about 9,000,000 rows but no rows deleted what is the problem?

```
 DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE  last_change < 1332201600 && last_change !=0
```

//1332201600 is time stamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting 9 million rows from a large table may take a long time. No rows will be deleted until the entire command completes and the transaction is committed. You have to be patient.

I would also check that your WHERE clause actually matches some rows. Try running this statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE last_change < 1332201600 && last_change !=0
LIMIT 10
```

If this returns 10 rows (and it should if the information in your question is correct) then your original DELETE statement will delete *at least* those 10 rows.

Comment: the problem is query finished but no rows deleted

Comment: @babakfaghihian: Did you run it inside a transaction? Have you committed the transaction? Did you notice when it said "x rows affected"? Can you remember what the reported value of x was?

Comment: i should delete this rows my question is why no rows deleted ?

Comment: 1) Mark Byers is correct - it's entirely possible for a "delete" to simply take a long time.  Until it's *completely* finished, you won't see *any* rows "deleted".  2) I'd much prefer this syntax (if possible): `where last_change < '2012-06-23 12:00 am' and last_change <> 0`  3) Have you checked the "where" to make sure any of the expected 9m rows match????

Answer (score 2):

Maybe problem is in and operator, and it should be:

```
DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE  last_change < 1332201600 AND last_change !=0
```

Comment: [AND and &&](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) are the same. (I do agree that it is better to use `AND` but I don't think it will solve the problem).

Comment: I agree, and I'd go further: `... where last_change < '2012-06-23 12:00 am' and last_change <> 0`